# Perimeters of the cells of a convex tessellation

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $C$ be a compact, convex region in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and say we have scalars $a_i, b_i, c_i$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.  Consider the tessellation $R_1,\dots,R_n$ of $C$ defined by letting $$R_{i}=\{(x,y)\in C:a_{i}x+b_{i}y+c_{i}\geq a_{j}x+b_{j}y+c_{j}~\text{for all }j\}~.$$
My question:  is there a mathematically compact way to describe the *perimeters* of the regions $R_i$ as a function of the $a_i, b_i, c_i$?  Of course, in practice, a brute-force computation would be completely easy, but I'm wondering if there's any sort of "surprising" identity that the perimeters would satisfy (even if it would be inefficient in practice).

For example (and I am pretty sure that the answer to this question is "no"), is there any sort of function $f(a_i,b_i,c_i)$ such that the perimeter of each $R_i$ is some sort of partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $a_i, b_i, c_i$?